# Amadeus Car Availability

Tags: c#, amadeus, availability

If I can invoke the api Car Availability with a `locationDescription.name` that have more than three letters the api send me the following errors:

> "18|Presentation|Serializing/Deserializing error: [type = DataElement]
>   [name = name] [Error = Invalid length for data element]."

Could you help, please?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, it is not a problem with serialitation but probablu it's a problem for the object filled to invoke amadeus when a city is not a iata code (more than three letters) so I need the correct object to fill

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your class does not have public default constructor.

Refer : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/330592/error-message-when-you-serialize-a-class-by-using-the-xmlserializer-cl

> When you try to use the XmlSerializer class to serialize a class that
>   does not have a public default constructor, you may receive the
>   following System.InvalidOperationException exception error message: An
>   unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in system.xml.dll Additional information: There was an error
>   reflecting 'class'. where class indicates the class that the
>   XmlSerializer class tried to serialize.

Comment: That's not the error message that the OP has received though...